# Password reset page using PHP7 PDO?

Tags: php-7

new to PHP 7, done a login and registration page . I also have to finish an email and password form  where the correct parameters are shown and after that are new password and retype new password, and on submit password will be change.

I have class "Korisnik" with parameters: public $id; public $email; public $password; public $ime; public $telefon; public $slika;
and function:

```
public static function promeni_staru_lozinku($new_password, $id) {
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $db->update('Korisnik', 'UPDATE korisnici SET password = :password WHERE korisnici.id = :id;',

            [
                ':password' => $new_password,
                ':id' => $id
            ]
        );
        return $id;
    }
```

But I am not sure is that correct, because I have password in database, not a new_password.

Here is my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Promena lozinke</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script>
        function validate(){

            var a = document.getElementById("new_password").value;
            var b = document.getElementById("confirm_new_password").value;
            if (a!=b) {
               alert("Nove lozinke se ne podudaraju");
               return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<h3 id="logo">Promena lozinke</h3>

    <form onSubmit="return validate()" action="logika/promenilozinku.php" method="post">

        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Unesite e-mail"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Unesite staru lozinku"><br>
        <input type="password" name="new_password" id="new_password" placeholder="Unesite novu lozinku"><br>
        <input type="password" name="confirm_new_password" id="confirm_new_password" placeholder="Ponovite lozinku"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Izmeni">

    </form>


    <a class="login" href="http://localhost/domaci_peti/index.php">Prijava</a><br>
    <a class="register" href="http://localhost/domaci_peti/registracija.php">Registracija</a><br>


</body>
</html>
```

And I try to finish that, but it still not work:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['email'])) {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    die();
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/../tabele/Korisnik.php';

$korisnik = Korisnik::login($_POST['email'],
                            $_POST['password']);

if ($korisnik !== null) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['korisnik_id'] = $korisnik->id;
    $id = Korisnik::promeni_staru_lozinku( $_POST['new_password']
                                );

if ($id > 0) {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    die();
} else {
    header('Location: ../lozinka.php?error=1');
    die();
}
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Pogrešni podaci za prijavu\")</script>";
    header("Refresh: 1; url= ../index.php");
    die();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you be more specific as for your question? It is not very cleared where the problem is. As for _because I have password in database, not a new_password._, you are mixing database column with variable name

Comment: Thank you. I have password (current password) in form, and inputs: new password and confirm password. How I can update old password with my code?

Comment: Sorry, it has been ages I haven't done any PHP so I prefer not to answer directly. One hint is to check the database. Maybe the SQL query (`$db->update()`) was not or not correctly executed.